# Is this always true: fmap (foldr f z) . sequenceA = foldr (liftA2 f) (pure z)

Tags: haskell, proof

```
import Prelude hiding (foldr)

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable

left, right :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t (f a) -> f b
left f z = fmap (foldr f z) . sequenceA
right f z = foldr (liftA2 f) (pure z)
```

I have a strong suspicion that the expressions left and right are equal, but how to prove it?

Comment: Are you assuming all the suggested laws hold, otherwise I'd say the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming the laws hold. When proving this for t = [] I needed the composition, homomorphism and fmap laws of Applicative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's  a start at least:

```
\f z -> fmap (foldr f z) . sequenceA
== (definition of Foldable foldr)
\f z -> fmap (foldr f z . toList) . sequenceA
== (distributivity of fmap)
\f z -> fmap (foldr f z) . fmap toList . sequenceA
== (need to prove this step, but it seems intuitive to me)
\f z -> fmap (foldr f z) . sequenceA . toList

\f z -> foldr (liftA2 f) (pure z)
== (definition of Foldable foldr)
\f z -> foldr (liftA2 f) (pure z) . toList
```

If you can prove that `fmap toList . sequenceA = sequenceA . toList`, and that your original claim holds for `t = []` you should be good to go.

Comment: `fmap toList . sequenceA = sequenceA . toList` holds, see http://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/distributivity-in-horners-rule/, the post that lead me to this question. But I'd like to be able to prove this without going through lists.

Comment: Actually, thinking a bit more about it, going through lists makes a lot of sense when using foldr. Thanks!